# C++ store vector in array during loop

Tags: c++, matlab, loops, matrix

Hi I'm new to C++ and am trying to do something that is very easy to do with Matlab.  I have a for loop which computes a vector.  I would like to then store this vector so that I can access it outside of the loop.

```
for(ii=0; ii < numObs; ii++} {
    someVector = ...
    someMatrix[ii][:] = someVector
}
```

The someMatrix[ii][:] doesn't work of course, but that's what I would like to do.  Any help's appreciated, thanks!

Clarification: someVector is an 1xn element vector which is computed each time in the loop.  I simply want to store it in either a matrix or array (not sure what) so that I can call someMatrix[ii] and get the vector back.

Comment: A vector is not the same thing as a matrix. Please clarify whether you're looking to use some implementation of a `matrix` or `vector`.

Comment: FYI, may I suggest to look into Eigen. Excellent linear algebra library that should result friendly to Matlab users.

Comment: Also have a look at the [Armadillo c++ library](http://arma.sourceforge.net), which has a syntax [deliberately similar](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax) to Matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix; // matrix - vector of vectors
for(int i = 0; i < numObs; ++i) {
    std::vector<double> vec = ... // your calculations go here
    // if no C++11 - don't use std::move
    matrix.push_back(std::move(vec)); 
}
```

One of the drawbacks here is that you have to assure in calculation code that each `vector` will have same number of elements (the code above doesn't verify it).

Note, that this is definitely not the optimal way for handling matrices and I'd recommend you to take a look at some dedicated libraries (boost::numeric, OpenCV for image processing, Armadillo or one of a dozen others) if you want to perform serious computations on it.

Comment: `emplace_back`  with this example makes no difference. vec is already created.

Comment: @Dam my bad, it was supposed to be a `std::move` (idea was to avoid copying). Thanks for the notice